# read comma separated values from brackets with scanf()

Tags: c, struct, scanf

I have the following input:

```
((1828,299),(2729,2553),(2797,2929),(2200,1383),(2894,876))
```

and following struct:

```
struct x{
int a;
int b;
}
```

How can I read the input with scanf() to create an array of my structs?

I have tried

```
scanf("%[^, ()],%d", &arr);
    if (i % 2 == 0){
        arr[i].x = scanf("%d");
    }else
        arr[i].y = scanf("%d");
```

But when I tried to print these values out I got some strange characters

Comment: Where did you read that `scanf()` works with regular expressions?

Comment: I have seen some examples on stackoverflow. I am new to C

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: `"%[` scans character classes, not regular expressions, as per the C Standard.  The OP is misusing this format, like most new C programmers would. Older programmers tend to stay away from `scanf` and friends, and forget about all their quirks...

Comment: @chqrlie: Ah, now I see. Does it show that the last time I used `scanf()` was never?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: it does... and I side with you.  Conversely, the reason I know something about `scanf` is because I implemented it for a tiny (but standard) C library.  `scanf` is almost never the right tool for parsing. Just like `strncpy` should never have made its way into the Standard.  It is a pity so many beginners fall pray to its appeal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct x{
    int a;
    int b;
};

int count(const char *s){
    if(s == NULL ||  *s != '(')
        return 0;//bad
    int n, a, b, count = 0;
    for(;;){
        n = -1;
        if(2!=sscanf(++s, "(%d,%d)%n", &a, &b, &n) || n < 0){
            return 0;
        } else {
            s += n;
            ++count;
            if(*s == ',')
                continue;
            else if(*s == ')')
                return count;
            else
                return 0;
        }
    }
}
void set(struct x *a, const char *s){
    int n, c = 0;
    while(2==sscanf(++s, "(%d,%d)%n", &a[c].a, &a[c].b, &n)){
        s += n;
        ++c;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char *input = "((1828,299),(2729,2553),(2797,2929),(2200,1383),(2894,876))";
    int i, n = count(input);
    if(n == 0){
        printf("invalid format!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    struct x arr[n];
    set(arr, input);
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        printf("(%4d, %4d)\n", arr[i].a, arr[i].b);
    }

    return 0;;
}
```

Comment: Great solution. @BLUEPIXY: you are my hero. Will this work as well with user's input if I'll change the `char *input` to `getch()`?

Comment: Technically, the loop in `set` will not behave properly if there is a missing `)` after a pair of integers and invoke undefined behaviour.  Testing for properly formatted input with `scanf` is so error prone.

Comment: @chqrlie `set` is based on the assumption that the parse has been made in the `count`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: the `count()` function has the same problem: `sscanf(++s, "(%d,%d)%n", &a, &b, &n)` will not set `n` if the `)` is missing but will still return `2` if 2 integers have been parsed. The following will invoke undefined behavior in `s += n;`.  `scanf` and friends are almost useless.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: if you initialize `n` to `11`, you will not detect the third invalid format.  When you do `s += n` in all 3 test cases, `n` is uninitialized. Anything can happen, if `n` happens to be `11`, `s` will point to the `)`, if `n` is some huge number, the program may crash, UB.

Comment: @chqrlie oh! I see now. I thank you for your great acumen. i will fix.

Answer (score 3):

Incorrect use of `scanf()`

1. `scanf("%[^, ()],%d", ...)` expects to scan and form a string (`"%[^, ()]"`) and an `int` (`"%d"`).  Code only provided for a place to save the `int`.
2. Code did not check the return value form `scanf()`, so code if not aware of any scanning issues.

When data is a *line*, recommend to use `fgets()`, *then* parse it.  Could use `strtok() strtol() sscanf()`.  Various pros/cons to each.  Example:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXN (5)
// maximum size needed to print and `int`
#define INTSIZE (sizeof (int )* CHAR_BIT  / 3 + 3)
// Expect buffer size needed
#define EXPECTEDSIZE (1+(2*INTSIZE + 4) + 3)

void fooo() {
  int i;

  struct x {
    int a;
    int b;
  } xx[MAXN];
  char buf[EXPECTEDSIZE * 2]; // I favor 2x size buffers
  while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
    char *p = buf;
    if (*p++ != '(') {
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < MAXN; i++) {
      int n; // use %n to locate scan completion
      int cnt = sscanf(p, " (%d ,%d ) %n", &xx[i].a, &xx[i].b, &n);
      fprintf(stderr, "cnt = %d '%s'\n", cnt, p);
      if (cnt != 2) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
      p += n;
      if (p[0] != ',') {
        if (p[0] == ')') {
          i++;
          break; // Successfully reached the end
        }
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
      p++;
    }
    int j;
    for (j=0; j< i; j++) {
      printf("%d  (%d ,%d )\n", j, xx[j].a, xx[j].b);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Agree. `Handle_BadFormat_or_EOF()` is nothing more than place-holder code for OP.  As OP did not specify how to handle failures nor EOF.    When `cnt == EOF`, that would normally indicate the end of input.  Other values like 0 or 1 implies a format problem.  In any case, code likely needs to break out of the loop.  I think your code handled errors more gracefully, that is why I up voted it.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY  Yes, with last `)`,  `cnt == 0` , breaks the loop and is tested again with `if (*p++ != ')') {`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75037/discussion-between-chux-and-bluepixy).

Comment: `" (%d ,%d ) %n"` : Do not consume `,` of between the elements.(number,number)`,` <== . And this fail to read.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY You are correct my friend.  Code amended,

Comment: you have missed counting the number of the last element.

Comment: also Debug code is to be enclosed in `#if DEBUG ...#endif`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you got strange characters is that `scanf()` does not return the scanned value, it returns the number of items that matched the format.

You are invoking `scanf()` in a way that invokes undefined behavior. It expects a pointer to an integer as a parameter when you use the `"%d"` specifier, so the correct way would be

```
if (scanf("%d", &arr[i].x) == 1)
    /* succesful */
else
    /* error */
```

The `*scanf()` family of functions, are not capable of matching the pattern you want, either use a regular expressions library, or parse the string by splitting the `(value, value)` and then their contents separately.

One way that comes to my mind is to use `strtok()` with `"),"` but that wouldn't count the last element and would easily fail if there is a white space between the `")"` and `","` so, a state machine and parsing the string one character at a time might be the best way to do it.

This is an example of what I mean, I enjoyed writing this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct point
 {
    int x;
    int y;
 };

struct stack
 {
    char  *top;
    char **stack;
    size_t count;
    size_t size;
 };

void
stackinit(struct stack *stack)
 {
    if (stack == NULL)
        return;
    stack->top   = NULL;
    stack->stack = NULL;
    stack->count = 0;
    stack->size  = 0;
 }

void
stackfinish(struct stack *stack)
 {
    if (stack == NULL)
        return;
    free(stack->stack);

    stack->stack = NULL;
 }

char *
stacktop(struct stack *stack)
 {
    if ((stack == NULL) || (stack->count == 0))
        return NULL;
    return stack->stack[stack->count - 1];
 }

void
stackpush(struct stack *stack, char *value)
 {
    void *pointer;
    if (stack == NULL)
        return;
    if (stack->size == stack->count)
     {
        pointer = realloc(stack->stack, (stack->size + 100) * sizeof(char *));
        if (pointer == NULL)
            return;
        stack->stack = pointer;
        stack->size += 100;
     }

    if (stack->stack == NULL)
        return;

    stack->stack[stack->count] = value;
    stack->count              += 1;
 }

void
stackpop(struct stack *stack)
 {
    if ((stack == NULL) || (stack->count <= 0))
        return;
    stack->count              -= 1;
    stack->stack[stack->count] = NULL;
 }

void
extractpoint(char *string, struct point **points, size_t *count)
 {
    struct point point;
    void        *pointer;
    char        *tail;
    if ((string == NULL) || (points == NULL) || (count == NULL))
        return;
    tail = strchr(string, ')');
    if (tail == NULL)
        return;
    if (sscanf(string, "%d,%d", &point.x, &point.y) != 2)
        return;
    pointer = realloc(*points, (1 + count[0]) * sizeof(*points));
    if (pointer == NULL)
        return;
    points[0]             = pointer;
    points[0][count[0]++] = point;
 }

void
parse(char *input, struct point **points, size_t *count)
 {
    struct stack stack;

    stackinit(&stack);
    while (*(input++) != '\0')
     {
        char *top;
        switch (*input)
         {
        case '(':
            stackpush(&stack, input + 1);
            break;
        case ')':
            stackpop(&stack);
            break;
        case ',':
            top = stacktop(&stack);
            if (top == NULL)
                continue;
            extractpoint(top, points, count);
            break;
        default:
            break;
         }
     }
    stackfinish(&stack);

    return;
 }

int
main(void)
 {
    char          input[] = "((1828,299),((2729,2553),(2797,2929),(2200,1383),(2894,876))";
    size_t        count   = 0;
    struct point *points  = NULL;
    size_t        index   = 0;

    parse(input, &points, &count);
    for (index = 0 ; index < count ; ++index)
        fprintf(stdout, "%zu: %d, %d\n", index, points[index].x, points[index].y);
    free(points);

    return 0;
 }
```